# Just want an executable to enumarate processes and enumarate loaded .dlls

Tags: winapi, dll, process, proxy

I want to make like a function with an argument `stdvector::<std::string>` of process names and `std::vector<std::string>` of .dll's to find in them and feed it into a function and get like PROCESSENTRY32 info `std::vector<PROCESSENTRY32>` returned of anything that matches the names.

You can google but won't find much as I have thanks for helping new to winapi but not to figuring things out

Answer (score 1):

There is a perfect example to do exactly what you want [on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The relevant code is copied below. As the introduction to the sample says

> To determine which processes have loaded a particular DLL, you must enumerate the modules for each process. The following sample code uses the [`EnumProcessModules`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to enumerate the modules of current processes in the system.

Now the sample code

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>

// To ensure correct resolution of symbols, add Psapi.lib to TARGETLIBS
// and compile with -DPSAPI_VERSION=1

int PrintModules( DWORD processID )
{
    HMODULE hMods[1024];
    HANDLE hProcess;
    DWORD cbNeeded;
    unsigned int i;

    // Print the process identifier.
    printf( "\nProcess ID: %u\n", processID );

    // Get a handle to the process.
    hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ,
        FALSE, processID );
    if (NULL == hProcess)
        return 1;

    // Get a list of all the modules in this process.
    if( EnumProcessModules(hProcess, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &cbNeeded))
    {
        for ( i = 0; i < (cbNeeded / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++ )
        {
            TCHAR szModName[MAX_PATH];

            // Get the full path to the module's file.
            if ( GetModuleFileNameEx( hProcess, hMods[i], szModName,
                sizeof(szModName) / sizeof(TCHAR)))
            {
                // Print the module name and handle value.
                _tprintf( TEXT("\t%s (0x%08X)\n"), szModName, hMods[i] );
            }
        }
    }

    // Release the handle to the process.
    CloseHandle( hProcess );

    return 0;
}

int main( void )
{

    DWORD aProcesses[1024]; 
    DWORD cbNeeded; 
    DWORD cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;

    // Get the list of process identifiers.
    if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) )
        return 1;

    // Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.
    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    // Print the names of the modules for each process.
    for ( i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ )
    {
        PrintModules( aProcesses[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The only change you will need to make is to `push-back` the module names of interest to your `std::vector<std::string>` beforehand and then search that vector with the enumerated module names instead of printing them.